# How to make Bootstrap collapse button open upward?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added the bootstrap collapse bar to my menu, it is working as it should, however since I have a unique nav bar that is in a fixed footer, it's not expanding and showing the nested content when the button is hit.

My educated guess is because it drops DOWN and there is no space under my footer as it's the lowest element on the page. Is there a way to make the direction go upward?

[Here is a link to the site](http://thesemachinesarewinning.com/), so hopefully the source code will be enough. If not please let me know what you would like me to post on here.

It's also important to point out that I've tested this in the header and it does not function there either...

Comment: There's a problem with jQuery on your page: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". Try to fix this and see if it works.

Comment: Which button is supposed to show what dropdown menu?

Comment: @Tqn when you make the browser size small enough ( about 750px wide or less ) you will notice the nav tabs in the footer will disappear and the bootstrap hamburger button will appear. That is the button I am trying to get to expose the hidden nav tabs...

Comment: @gregory I fixed it, but I'm afraid it's still not working.

Comment: Your markup does not match Bootstraps conventions... see here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default and http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom

Comment: @gregory I added the fixed bottom class and a bottom padding to the body. I'm still not sure if my data-target is correct or what I'm missing. It's still not doing what it should. <div class="wrapper navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">